# Спаму место в комментариях?

Tags: обсуждение, инструменты-модератора

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761299/178988 - был вот этот ответ с тревогой *невежливый или оскорбительный,* я преобразовал его в комментарий к вопросу и тревога автоматически пометилась как полезная. На мой взгляд, гораздо логичнее было бы помечать как спорную или вообще отклонять, нет?

Answer (score 2):

Если по мнению модератора такая серьёзная тревога как "спам/оскорбление" не соответствует действительности, то её наверное стоит отклонить, или пометить спорной, если всё таки потребовались какие-то активные действия со стороны модератора. Если преобразование в комментарий автоматически помечает такую тревогу полезной, это, конечно, выглядит странно. Но может быть здесь предполагается, что после преобразования в комментарий, текст будет несколько изменен модератором для исключения той части, которая была расценена как "спам/оскорбление". При текущем поведении получается нужно сначала обработать тревогу, а после уже производить манипуляции над самим сообщением.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по временной шкале, данный ответ набрал целую пачку тревог:

- Сначала он был отмечен автоматически как ответ низкого качества.
- Затем получил тревогу как спам или оскорбления.
- Далее получил три тревоги как сообщение, не содержащее ответа от участников сообщества.
- Попал на проверку.
- На проверке был рекомендован к удалению.
- Получил еще одну тревогу, что сообщение не содержит ответ.

Проверка в очереди ответов низкого качества, при этом, не была завершена, а обработка тревог значится за модератором, преобразовавшим ответ в комментарий (за вами).

[Несколько похожий ответ на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253244/) поясняет, что если сообщение получает тревогу как не содержащее ответа, то оно помещается сразу в две очереди: (1) сообщений низкого качества и (2) очередь для поверки модераторам. Если в очереди низкого качества проверяющие отмечают сообщение как рекомендованное к удалению, тревога отмечается полезной автоматически (и наоборот, если оставляют — отклоняется). У модераторов, в свою очередь, есть возможность обрабатывать тревогу вручную — выбрать, является она полезной или нет.

Мне кажется, если вы руками не отмечали тревогу полезной, система сделала это за вас, опираясь на результаты в очереди проверок. Опять же, это догадки, потому что я не знаю, каким образом вы набрели на данный ответ (через поиск, через очередь тревог для модераторов или через очередь проверок сообщений низкого качества).

---

Конкретно этот ответ: в комментариях ему тоже не место, высказывание из «ответа» неуместно и должно быть (было) удалено.

Comment: _"система сделала это за вас, опираясь на результаты в очереди проверок"_ - я говорил про тревогу "спам или оскорбление" - она не попадает в очередь проверок же? А по остальным тревогам вопросов нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy Она также значится обработанной вами как «полезная». Могу лишь предположить, что там некая аналогичная закрытию вопросов система (где результат голосования определяется большинством голосов).

Comment: Скорее, там другой механизм: если ответ удаляется, то тревоги спама автоматически признаются полезными - встречал это и раньше. Чтобы сделать спорными, надо их явно сбросить. Но ведь преобразование в комментарий - это не совсем удаление. А судя по всему, отрабатывает та же проверка - ответ удалён, значит тревога полезная.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тоже думал об этом, но на сколько я помню, кода я удалял ответы, тревоги на них оставались не обработанными. Я еще у ребят уточнил. Посмотрим, что ответят.

Comment: Я вчера удалял - ставилось, что полезная. После удаления панель тревоги не исчезает, но даже если там отклонить, то уже поздно и в истории тревога помечена как полезная.

Comment: @Qwertiy Как я понял, все–таки, во время удаления сообщения тревога (все тревоги на сообщении!) отмечается полезной.

Comment: Ну так вот именно...